# Using max(col) with count in sub-query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am putting together a query in SQL Server but having issues with the sub-query
I wish to use the `max(loadid)` and count the number of records the query returns.

So for example my last loadid is 400 and the amount of records with 400 is 2300, so I would my `recor_count` column should display 2300. I have tried various ways below but am getting errors.

```
select count (loadid) 
from t1 
where loadid = (select max(loadid) from t1) record_count;

(select top 1 LOADID, count(*) 
 from t1
 group by loadid
 order by count(*) desc) as Record_Count
```

Comment: What are the errors? The code as submitted has errors, for example missing closing brackets etc. Your first one is very close. Just move the `record_count` alias to just after the `count(loadid)` expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be easier to achieve with a window function in the inner query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY loadid DESC) AS rk
        FROM   t1) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Showing `loadid` and number of matching rows with the use of grouping, ordering by count and limiting the output to 1 row with `top`.

```
select top 1 loadid, count(*) as cnt
from t1
group by loadid
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but when i try this i receive: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: @Georgep2000 I believe that query was intended to be used as is and not as a subquery in a larger query.

Comment: @Georgep2000 shawnt00 is right. You did not specify it needs to be used as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Another simplest way to achieve the result :

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @Test Table
(
    Id      Int
)

Insert Into @Test(Id) Values
(397),(398),(399),(400)

Declare @Abc Table
(
     Id     Int
    ,Value  Varchar(100)
)

INsert Into @Abc(Id,Value) Values
 (398,'')
,(400,'')
,(397,'')
,(400,'')
,(400,'')

Select   a.Id
        ,Count(a.Value) As RecordCount
From    @Abc As a
        Join
        (
            Select  Max(t.Id) As Id
            From    @Test As t
        ) As v On a.Id = v.Id
Group By a.Id
```